# LogicException: Container extension "security" is not registered

Tags: security, symfony, containers

Hi i just try to install symfony 2.1.3 but when i try to go to the configuration. 
I've got the error "LogicException: Container extension "security" is not registered".
I have move nothing in script et made the install with composer.
Does anyone have an idea? Is it a bug of symfony?
Thks a lot

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a help file? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: I try all post there talking about that!!!

Comment: And the documentation say nothing about this problem!!!!